# LinkedIN: Block automatically loggedIn without asking allow access ( JavaScript )

Tags: php, linkedin-api

In my appliaction I have used linkedIn API to login. If the user is already loggedIn in the linkedIn in same browser and pressing linkedin login button in my website , the user will automatically loggedin to my website. But i want to ask 'Allow Access' popup authentication window provided by linkedIn.

**EDIT :**  using Samer Bechara answer

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {   
    if ( settings.url == "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate" ) {
           settings.url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"   
    } 


 });
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: apikey goes here
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
      authorize: false
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onLinkedInLoad() {
       IN.ENV.js.scope = new Array();
       IN.ENV.js.scope[0] = "r_emailaddress";
       IN.ENV.js.scope[1] = "r_contactinfo";  

       //IN.User.authorize();
       IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
      }




      function onLinkedInAuth() {

        IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id,firstName,lastName,headline,emailAddress,mainAddress,phoneNumbers").result(displayProfiles);
      }

      function displayProfiles(profiles) {

        member = profiles.values[0];
        var phs="";
        var mid =member.id;
        var eid= member.emailAddress;
        var mad= member.mainAddress;
        var ln= member.lastName;
        var fn= member.firstName;
         var json = JSON.stringify(profiles);
         var ph=member.phoneNumbers._total;

         if(ph >0){
          phs=member.phoneNumbers.values[0].phoneNumber;
         }


      }

    </script>
```

Comment: someone said make authorize: false it will work. But really it wont

Comment: Actually What I need is, if the user already loggedIn in linkedIn.com his login details are exists in the cookies. when he come to my website without clear the cookies and simply pressing my linkedIn button without showing allow access dialog, he entered into my application

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, you should change your OAuth endpoint from https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize. This should work for you.

However, this cannot be done using the Javascript-based API, because their JS file is obsfucated, for security purposes. The only way to do so is to move your authentication system to the server side (e.g. PHP), which allows you to change the authorization endpoint yourself.

**Edit**

You can use the `jQuery.ajaXSend()` method as follows to modify the request. I haven't tested this, but should work for you.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {   
    if ( settings.url == "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate" ) {
           settings.url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"   
    } 
});
```

Comment: so is there no option to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use the jQuery .ajaxSend method to manipulate the ajax request. Haven't tested this though. Updating my answer to reflect changes..

Comment: Code hasn't been tested, it's an example. You need to take it from there. In any case, like I previously said, the best way would be to use server-side API.